# Cleaning walls or painting

Tags: paint

When white walls get kind of filthy due to smoking or dirty finger here and there, is the only solution to paint over? Or is there any product that could clean them once in a year or so to keep them fresh looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is "clean walls **AND** paint," if you're going to paint at all. Even if you do decide to paint over a stain you can't remove, you still need to clean the wall to make sure the paint adheres properly.

I use [TSP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001GOGQW) to wipe down the walls or surfaces prior to repainting. It cuts the level of surface gloss, *really* cuts through grease, and gives you a nice clean surface for new paint - all with a quick wipe down and minimal scrubbing.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used a grout sponge, cold water and dawn.  If the cleaning takes off the paint then you need to repaint of course but most of the time soap and water works.  Obviously doesn't help that much with an intense smoke smell (but painting might not either).

Answer (score 0):

Javex  or bleach diluted in water will clean with a sponge or flat floor mop rinsed often. If too Strong and scrubbed , it can remove stains or slowly remove paint as well.

Answer (score 0):

In UK we use sugar soap to treat dirt from smoking before painting the wall. I suppose you can use it without consecutive painting.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the quality of the paint and the sheen really.  Generally speaking the closer to a gloss finish the easier it is to clean.  Glossy surfaces are going to be less porous than flat surfaces, therefore easier to clean.

If you decide to paint, like other answers have mentioned, always sand and clean the walls before hand.  Prep work is very important for paint adhesion.

A simple mixture of vinegar and water is a good cleaning agent for paint as it is less corrosive than a chemical cleaning agent.